# Error: else without if. What went wrong?

Tags: java, if-statement

The following code produces a compilation error of `else` without `if`. Everything else is fine. I would also like to know how to comment something out.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CalcRunner
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        System.out.println("Enter 1 to Add, 2 to Subtract, 3 to Divide, or 4 to Multiply");
        int x = keyboard.nextInt();

        if (x == 1);
        {
            System.out.println("Enter an integer");
            int num1 = keyboard.nextInt();

            System.out.println("Enter another integer");
            int num2 = keyboard.nextInt();

            System.out.println("The sum of the numbers equals " + (num1+num2));
        }
        if (x == 2);
        {
            System.out.println("Enter an integer");
            int num1 = keyboard.nextInt();

            System.out.println("Enter another integer");
            int num2 = keyboard.nextInt();

            System.out.println("The sum of the numbers equals " + (num1-num2));
        }
        if (x == 3);
        {
            System.out.println("Enter an integer");
            int num1 = keyboard.nextInt();

            System.out.println("Enter another integer");
            int num2 = keyboard.nextInt();

            System.out.println("The sum of the numbers equals " + (num1/num2));
        }
        if (x == 4);
        {
            System.out.println("Enter an integer");
            int num1 = keyboard.next=Int();

            System.out.println("Enter another integer");
            int num2 = keyboard.nextInt();

            System.out.println("The sum of the numbers equals " + (num1*num2));
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.print("Error 510038585832857329457294547243344684643734");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `if();` is equivalent to `if() {}`.

Comment: Folks, what's with all the downvoting? Yes, it's a fairly basic syntax error **if you know Java** (or anything else with B-like syntax). If you **don't**, it's not a dumb question. Newcomers to B-like languages frequently have trouble with where the semicolons do and don't go.

Comment: @ user: *"I would also like to know how to comment something out."* Ask **one** question per question on SO. (And the answer to that question really is ***trivially easy to find*** in any basic tutorial or even by searching for "comment" in the Java Language specification. Maybe that's what the votes are about.)

Comment: Repeating the question text **eleven** times (see rev 1, probably to pass the minimum question length check) didn't make any friends, and it's a duplicate.

Comment: This is one good jibe on error messages the like we have encountered every now and then `System.out.print("Error 510038585832857329457294547243344684643734");`. Shouldn't we upvote because of that?

Comment: @AndrewMedico: OMG, I didn't see it until Ondkloss's fix. Yeah, that is Not Cool. The code block should have got it past the question length, maybe that was a ninja edit and the OP didn't remove the rubbish. Yikes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do it with a switch :

```
public static void main(String args[])
        {
            System.out.println("Enter 1 to Add, 2 to Subtract, 3 to Divide, or 4 to Multiply");
            int x = keyboard.nextInt();

    switch(x){
            case 1:

                System.out.println("Enter an integer");
                int num1 = keyboard.nextInt();

                System.out.println("Enter another integer");
                int num2 = keyboard.nextInt();

                System.out.println("The sum of the numbers equals " + (num1+num2));
            break;
            case 2:

                System.out.println("Enter an integer");
                num1 = keyboard.nextInt();

                System.out.println("Enter another integer");
                num2 = keyboard.nextInt();

                System.out.println("The sum of the numbers equals " + (num1-num2));
            break;
            case 3:

                System.out.println("Enter an integer");
                num1 = keyboard.nextInt();

                System.out.println("Enter another integer");
                num2 = keyboard.nextInt();

                System.out.println("The sum of the numbers equals " + (num1/num2));
            break;
            case 4:

                System.out.println("Enter an integer");
                num1 = keyboard.next=Int();

                System.out.println("Enter another integer");
                num2 = keyboard.nextInt();

                System.out.println("The sum of the numbers equals " + (num1*num2));
            break;
            default:

                System.out.print("Error 510038585832857329457294547243344684643734");
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Should be named Boris the Speeder :)

Answer (score 7):

Change

`if (x == 1);`

to

`if (x == 1)`

The semi-colon is wrong in this context. It causes the `{...}` block following it to always be executed.

And you might want to replace the `if` statements with `if`-`else if`-...-`else`:

```
if (x == 1) {
...
} else if (...) {
...
} else if (...) {
...
else {
...
}
```

since if one of the conditions evaluates to true, non of the others can evaluate to true, and I'm assuming you wish the `else` clause to be executed only if all the conditions are false (and not just the last condition).

Or better yet, use a switch statement.

Comment: actually all the if statements are wrong too

Comment: The semi-colon is not *wrong* it's translated to `if(x == 1) { }`.. It shouldn't be here in this case, but saying it's wrong might confuse OP.

Comment: @MarounMaroun Beg to differ--saying it's **not** wrong might confuse everyone.  It's "syntactically legal", but still **wrong**.  There is no valid reason to ever use this syntax on an `if`.  (There is, sometimes, on a `while` or `for`.  But never on an `if`.)

Comment: @MarounMaroun I would think that, whilst correct, saying that `if();` is equivalent to `if(){}` is _more_ confusing to the OP. Better to say that `if();{}` is the same as `if(){} {}` where the second block is always executed.

Comment: @ajb That's what I meant to say :) Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 0):

The if else statements are implemented like this.
see the code i edited for You.

you else if for subsequent  if statements.

```
if (x == 1)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter an integer");
        int num1 = keyboard.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter another integer");
        int num2 = keyboard.nextInt();

        System.out.println("The sum of the numbers equals " + (num1+num2));
    }
    else if (x == 2)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter an integer");
        int num1 = keyboard.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter another integer");
        int num2 = keyboard.nextInt();

        System.out.println("The sum of the numbers equals " + (num1-num2));
    }
    else if (x == 3)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter an integer");
        int num1 = keyboard.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter another integer");
        int num2 = keyboard.nextInt();

        System.out.println("The sum of the numbers equals " + (num1/num2));
    }
    else if (x == 4)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter an integer");
        int num1 = keyboard.next=Int();

        System.out.println("Enter another integer");
        int num2 = keyboard.nextInt();

        System.out.println("The sum of the numbers equals " + (num1*num2));
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.print("Error 510038585832857329457294547243344684643734");
    }
}
```